# How to set Theme Option Page as Dashboard home page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to set Theme Option Page [or] plugin option page as Admin Dashboard home page in Wordpress.

Otherwise, I would like to land on my Theme Option Page or plugin option page as soon as user log into Admin Dashboard

Comment: What do you mean? This is not clear. Do you mean you would like to land on your Theme Option Page or plugin option page as soon as you log into Admin?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, then use this :

```
function redirect_after_login(){
         return 'http://yourwordpressurl';
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "redirect_after_login", 10, 3);
```

The hook login_redirect has the redirect url, so filter it to give it whatever value you want.